# .gradle folder in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, github, gradle

I'm working on a flutter project and it's not very clear to me why every time I push on GitHub the project there are always some files in the .gradle folder that changes or get created,
they usually look like this
6.7/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin   or 6.7/javaCompile/javaCompile.lock
and I was wondering what they are for and maybe how not to change them every time I push because sometimes they make issues with my coworkers.

Comment: What's in your `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 1):

That directory is usually added to the .gitignore file. If you create a new flutter project then inside the android folder there is a .gitignore with the following:

```
gradle-wrapper.jar
/.gradle
/captures/
/gradlew
/gradlew.bat
/local.properties
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# Remember to never publicly share your keystore.
# See https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app
key.properties
**/*.keystore
**/*.jks
```

I'd personally recommend talking to the other developers and making sure that there isn't a reason it's not included in the .gitignore file and then if there is no reason, add it to the gitignore file.

Comment: this is interesting, I've got those exact files in my .gitignore  but they are added every time I push, do anyone might know why?

Comment: If someone committed them at one point then they will always be tracked. You'll have to remove those files, commit the change and then they should be ignored from then on. Everyone on your team will probably have to at least run flutter clean before they rebuild their project after that change is made.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem is that I had that folder in the `.gitignore`, but the folder was still *tracked*. I had to untrack the folder and then the problem was solved.